# ERRO: "MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. "

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am unable to connect the mongoose with my application. It shows an error which is "MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist"

When I  set the IP address as 0.0.0.0 it works properly. But this method only works while development. I would like to connect the database through my current IP Address.

Here is the code.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const Connection = async () => {
    const URL = `mongodb+srv://*****:*****@chittagongpestcontrol.hviumcx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(URL, { useNewUrlParser: true})
        console.log('Databease connect successfully.')
    } catch(error) {
        console.log('Error while connecting with the database.',error);
    }
}

export default Connection;
```

And the error it shows:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (D:\Web\Node JS project\chittagongepestcontrol\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:792:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (D:\Web\Node JS project\chittagongepestcontrol\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:767:11)
    at async Connection (file:///D:/Web/Node%20JS%20project/chittagongepestcontrol/server/database/db.js:6:9) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-jodubob-shard-00-01.hviumcx.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-jodubob-shard-00-00.hviumcx.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-jodubob-shard-00-02.hviumcx.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-bwulgu-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```